# Is it possible to modify server reply on transit

Tags: javascript, security, srp-protocol

I am building a javascript library that will allow authentication to server using SRP-6 protocol.

I know using javascript as an authentication method is not the best option due to XSS. But proper XSS prevention can eliminate most issues.

My only concern is how easy it is to modify a server reply before the user even receives the request?

Sample Scenario:

User request page: `http://serverdomain/home`

Server:
Replies back with:

```
<html>
   <head>Home</head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="auth.js"></script>
   <body>Home</body>
</html>
```

Before user receives the reply. Can a hacker somehow magically modify the reply to

```
<html>
   <head>Home</head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="hacker_auth.js"></script>
   <body>Home</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible to do? This is one of the vulnerability that I can think of when using javascript to authenticate.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack ?

Comment: yes, it's possible, there's many ways to do it.

Comment: @Badaboooooom That's the term that I am looking for thanks!

Comment: @RichardHeath, and it's not restricted to javascript. Any form of unsheathed communication between client and server can be intercepted

Comment: You should use SRP over HTTPS as they are complimentary and it gives some additional defences against such attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badaboooooom nailed it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack  You can use https to mitigate the risk, though tools such as http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/ still make an attack possible if the user doesn't notice the "lock" is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this using a secure protocol like HTTPS, though everything can be hacked some way, some are just more easily broken than others.